# CAN Bus Shield Initialization Failed

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, can-bus

**The Problem**

I've been working on a project that requires the use of a CAN Bus Shield v2 on an Arduino. For most of the time it has worked great, completely as intended. But recently, I was trying to hookup a 24V heater to a MOSFET to be controlled by the Arduino. I had hooked it up the pin 2 which later I found out was a bad idea because pin 2 is for the interrupt signal. I uploaded the code and the heater did not turn on.

A while later I tried to upload code to the Arduino and it would not upload, citing a not in sync error. So, switched the Arduino board out for another one of the same model and the code uploaded just fine. But, the CAN Shield was throwing a "CAN Bus Shield Init FAILED" error over and over again. And the INT light was staying permanently on. And the Rx light would stay on if I tried to send a message on the bus from another node.

My question is, will I have to purchase a new shield or is there a way to fix this?

**What I have tried**

- Turning it off and on again
- Using the shield on the old Arduino
- Wiping the Arduino and adding the code again
- Reverting to an older piece of code
- Setting pin 2 HIGH (this turned off the INT light but did not fix the init problem)
- Sending various messages on the CAN Bus
- Flipping the OBD switch on/off
- Trying different resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXQW4d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sounds like maybe a bad wiring issue where you fried the Arduino? Can you post a wiring diagram? You can use the "Schematic" button in the editor when editing your question.